# Не діалектний відповідник до слова "дружба"

Tags: значення-слів

На Тернопільщині наречений зазвичай запрошує двох "[дружбів](http://sum.in.ua/s/druzhba)":

> Товариш молодого, що бере участь у весільному обряді.

Як бачите, в СУМі це слово має позначку "застаріле" та "діалектне". Цікавить чи є якийсь сучасний та не діалектний варіант?

Знаю, що на Хмельниччині молодий запрошує "[свідка](http://sum.in.ua/s/svidok)". Одне зі значень цього слова в СУМі (3):

> Особа, присутня при чому-небудь для офіційного підтвердження дійсності
>   або правильності чогось.

І приклад:

> Наречені розписуються. До столу підходять свідки молодого і молодої

Можливо, цей варіант можна використати як відповідник (хоч, можливо, свідок лише засвідчує шлюб, але не бере участь у всіх весільних обрядах).

Comment: Я не певен, що СУМ в цьому випадку хороше джерело. Слова "дружба" і "дружка" широко вживані і є нормою мови для міської та сільської молоді принаймні на всій Галичині (Льв-ІФ-Тер). На них зав'язано багато народних весільних пісень. 
Ще один момент: весільні традиції Галичини і центральної частини України помітно різняться. На Галичині за звичай на весіллях є дві пари дружба/дружка і часто робиться чітка різниця між "першим дружбою" й "другим дружбою" тоді як на Сході часто є тільки одна пара свідків.